# Get selected number of items in kendo listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

How do I get the total number of selected items?

This doesn't work.

```
var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
alert(floorPlanlistView.select().length());
```

Comment: `.length` is not a function I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
alert(floorPlanlistView.select().length);
```